# View files saved after specific date in unix

Tags: unix, grep

I try to open a group of files which were saved  after a specific date using the following command

View /*/*log | grep 'Aug 30'

But I get a message as 
Vim: warning : output is not to a terminal

And nothing happens.
Any suggestions???

Comment: @MarkSetchell  yeah I got u... I  got the output using 

Vi `ls -ltr ./*/*log | grep 'Aug 30' | awk '{print $9}'`

I made the vi to open the specific file ... Thanks for your answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are effectively telling `view` to open all the log files. You then tell it to send its output not to the screen as normal, but to another command called `grep`.

You probably want to use `find` to generate a list of files and then tell `view` to open them. So, to find files changed yesterday (1 day ago), you could use:

```
find /wherever/the/logs/are -name \*.log -mtime -1
```

Now, you want to edit those files, so pass the list to `view`:

```
view $(find /wherever/the/logs/are -name \*.log -mtime -1)
```